# testing endianness of system with the unix shell

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm very new to shell scripting (literally my first day) and I'm using it to create portable C code for one of my classes. I'd like to define a CPP directive which will define the endianness of the system I'm compiling on (whether that be Solaris, BSD, Linux, OSX, etc. bu tI'm having a bit of difficulty.

The key to my current script is the following line:

```
printf '\1' | od -dAn;
```

This outputs `1` for little endian and `256` for big endian (I've tested it on all my systems and it appears to do the job).

Now, when I add it to the following script, it doesn't appear to play nicely.

```
CONFIG_HRD="config.h"
ENDIAN=printf '\1' | od -dAn;

touch $CONFIG_HRD
if $ENDIAN -eq \1; then
    echo "#define LITTLE_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
else
    echo "#define BIG_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
fi
```

It fails with the following errors

```
./script.sh: line 2: \1: command not found
./script.sh: line 5: -eq: command not found
```

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

====== edit=======
The following code now produces the error below:

```
CONFIG_HRD="config.h"
ENDIAN=$(printf '\1' | od -dAn)

touch $CONFIG_HRD
if `$ENDIAN -eq 1`; then
    echo "#define LITTLE_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
else
    echo "#define BIG_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
fi
```

This error:

```
./script.sh: line 5: 1: command not found
```

---

This code results in the following error:

```
CONFIG_HRD="config.h"
ENDIAN=$(printf '\1' | od -dAn)

touch $CONFIG_HRD
if `$ENDIAN=1`; then
    echo "#define LITTLE_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
else
    echo "#define BIG_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
fi
```

Error:

```
./script.sh: line 5: 1=1: command not found
```

and this one (brackets instead of ticks) results in another error:

```
CONFIG_HRD="config.h"
ENDIAN=$(printf '\1' | od -dAn)

touch $CONFIG_HRD
if [$ENDIAN=1]; then
    echo "#define LITTLE_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
else
    echo "#define BIG_ENDIAN" >> $CONFIG_HRD
fi
```

Error:

```
./script.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: Have you considered using Autoconf (https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)? It is specifically designed for doing things like this, and produces a shell script as its final product.

Comment: that's next homework, but the point of this assignment is to learn how to make do without I suppose

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/163487/how-to-tell-if-a-linux-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
ENDIAN=$(printf '\1' | od -dAn)
```

or (with back ticks)

```
ENDIAN=`printf '\1' | od -dAn`
```

to store the result into var.

Depends on the shell that you are using the syntax for `if` too.

```
if [ $ENDIAN -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Great, that solves one problem. However, I still get another problem at line 5 regarding `1` being a command. I will update the OP with my edited script code

Comment: And I've tried with both `-eq` and `=` with the same result

Comment: Try `if [ "$ENDIAN" -eq 1 ]; then`. During debugging, start your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` to get trace.

Comment: `[ $ENDIAN -eq 1 ]` works here. Did you use square brackets ? In your post you are using back ticks.

Comment: You must preserve spaces.